# Android, Material Design, RecyclerView doesn't show elements

Tags: android, material-design

I have a question related to Material Design introduced in Android 5. I'm very new with UX interfaces. Now I'm trying to implement simple music player with fragment for choosing songs from storage.  Actually, that fragment contains RecyclerView. But RecyclerView doesn't show any element (it contains views with one TextView), even simple "..". I checked it with log-tracking and found that function "onBindViewHolder" was called correctly. To be honest, I have no idea what is wrong with my code. Obviously, I provide link to my project: [UX](https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/UX_Music)
I will be gratefull for any suggestion, advice or may be pointer to the mistake.

Comment: You probably should post the problematic code in your question rather posting than a link to your entire project. It raises the chances that your question will be answered. 

And you may want to give the help center a read.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Problem in this that I don;t know which part of code is causing the issue. It seems like code is OK, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I think most people will not be willing read through all that, you may have better chances to solve your problem by debugging it yourself. The following blog post may be useful http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Ye, I know. But I thought that maybe someone meet this problem before, so he can answer my question.